# Zero knowledge proofs for a Merkle Tree

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, hash-tree

Say I have a publicly available Merkle tree, and I want to prove the existence of a leaf (containing a number, maybe) in the tree. 
I could give the path along with the siblings, for a normal Merkle proof, but this reveals the leaf itself.

How can I do this in zero knowledge, i.e., proving that the leaf exists, but not revealing which leaf?

Comment: Is it possible, that you mean proving the leaf exists without revealing the content of the leaf?

Comment: Yes, maybe I should clarify a bit. A leaf is just a number, so it existing in the tree does not make it special to me, as compared to another number not in the tree.

Comment: I don't think the problem is well specified. In ZK proofs you typically have like a public instance of something, and a prover wants to prove something about it. What is the public instance here? Is the tree public?

Comment: @Daniel, Yes, the tree is public.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "path" is only a witness for your proof; you don't actually want to *give* the path to the verifier. Turns out that going from a NP-problem with witness to an actual zero-knowledge proof is not that trivial.

What you could do: one of your leaves $L_1, \dots, L_{n}$ has the value of your commitment $x$. You might write something like

$$\bigvee^{n}_{i=1}\left(L_i=x\right).$$

This is a satisfaction problem, so it's suited to be fed in a bunch of ZK libraries.

---

Lately, I've been playing with rank-1 constraint systems (r1cs), such as provided by [libsnark](https://github.com/scipr-lab/libsnark/tree/master/libsnark/relations/constraint_satisfaction_problems/r1cs) or in a little time by [dalek's ``bulletproof'' library](https://github.com/dalek-cryptography/bulletproofs/milestone/3). These provide non-interactive, fast, compact zero-knowledge proves.

You said your leaves could contain numbers. This translates very nicely in a r1cs system!

$$\prod^n_{i=1}(L_i-x)=0$$

You simply prove that one of the roots of the above polynomial equals zero, which is true when $x$ represents a leaf.

Comment: Thanks. I'll need to read a little more about this, though.

Comment: Sadly, there are not many decent resources on this that I can find, so make sure to ask these kind of questions here on crypto.SE. It's quite a nice question!

Comment: [Interstellar's spacesuit's spec](https://github.com/interstellar/spacesuit/blob/master/spec.md) document contains quite some documentation on how they use r1cs; IMO that gives quite some insight.

Comment: can this be done without r1cs?

Comment: While the answer is probably "yes", the answer to "how" becomes equally probably a lot more complex. You could have a look at [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1767/48404), where other users propose several systems that encode pre-image knowledge.