# Prove that I know string that hash to h

Tags: hash, zero-knowledge-proofs

Lets say `p = str` and  `h = SHA512(p)` i send the `h` which is the SHA512 of `p` to a friend using via email my friend in order to be sure that I'm the right person ask me to prove that I know the `p`. How can I can prove that I know `p` without disclosing it ??

As I have read so far its possible via zero-knowledge proof. Any pseudocode or python example are welcome.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving knowledge of a preimage of a hash without disclosing it?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1767/proving-knowledge-of-a-preimage-of-a-hash-without-disclosing-it)

Comment: There are more [questions tagged _zero-knowledge-proofs_ and _hash_](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zero-knowledge-proofs+hash).